# Is it possible to increment setw?

Tags: c++

I need to display something that looks like:

```
     /
    -
    /
   /
    -
    /
   /
  /
   -
```

I currently have the following which does not print the slashes properly.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfDolls; i++) {
   for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++) 
      cout << setw(numberOfDolls) << '/' << endl;
      
      cout << "-" << endl;
    }
```

I was thinking of using setw() to increment the slashes. Is this possible?

Comment: probably, but don't overthink it. There is space for another solution.

Comment: By "increment" you probably mean "indent"?

Comment: Start by reading documentation, for example here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw

Comment: @hyde yes, indent the spacing by 'numberOfDolls' amount and -1 each time

Comment: @hyde my question is how to get the slashes to print in a setw() - 1 type of way each new line like I tried to display above. I am unsure how/if you can increment indentation, if that makes sense

Comment: @hyde so I'm using the outer loop to control the number of slashes based on the number of dolls inputted by the user. Can I/should I also control the indentation for each line with the outer loop?

Comment: Looking at your expected figure, it is difficult to understand the logic about placement of the `-`.  Is there any mistake about the first one?

Comment: @Damien It is essentially supposed to be half of a doll figure, but christmas tree is very similar looking. I just need it to keep moving back one space each new line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure about your doubt but you will get desired output using following:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfDolls; i++) {
   for(int j = 1, n=numberOfDolls; j <= i; j++)
      cout << setw(n--) << '/' << endl;

      cout <<setw(numberOfDolls-1)<< "-" << endl;
    }
```

Comment: thank u this is exactly what i was trying to do using setw()

Comment: @wockywoad if this is what you were looking for then you can accept this as final answer. It will help community !

Answer (score 2):

You can use `std::setw(.)` for that purpose. The key is to have a parameter defining the shift. Here is a code implementing it. Simple modifications are possible if you want to slightly modify the image.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
int main() {

    int numberOfDolls = 3;
    int shift = numberOfDolls + 2;
    for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfDolls; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            std::cout << std::setw(shift) << '/' << std::endl;
            shift--;
        }
        shift++; 
        std::cout << std::setw(shift) << "-" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, using `std::setw(.)` seems like an overkill. In my opinion, better to simply add spaces, for example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
int main() {

    int numberOfDolls = 3;
    int shift = numberOfDolls + 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfDolls; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            std::cout << std::string(shift, ' ') << '/' << std::endl;
            shift--;
        }
        shift++; 
        std::cout << std::string(shift, ' ') << "-" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

*Output*

```
    /
    -
    /
   /
   -
   /
  /
 /
 -
```